# Proof. Maximum of the closure is equal to the supremum of the set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The exercise is:

> Show that if $A \subset \mathbb{R} $ is bounded and $ A \neq \varnothing $ then $sup(A)=max(\overline{A} ).$

Now, I wanted to ask you **whether my proof is watertight**:

---

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-empty and bounded set.
>
> Then $A$ has a finite supremum $sup(A) \equiv \widetilde{x}$, which is
>   the least upper bound on $A$.
>
> Further define $\overline{x} \equiv max(\overline{A} )$.
>
> Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\overline{x} \neq
>  \widetilde{x}$, which implies that there exists a distance $
>  d(\overline{x}, \widetilde{x} ) \equiv \epsilon > 0$. Given that
>    $\widetilde{x} \geq x, \forall x \in A,$ we have that $B_{\epsilon /2}
>  (\overline{x}) \cap A = \varnothing $.
>
> This is a contradiction of the definition of closure.
>
> Therefore, $sup(A)=max(\overline{A} )$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Further define $\overline{x}=max(\overline{A})$." This is not allowed, as you need to prove that this is well-defined. Not every set has a maximum. Since the standard proof of this is done by showing that it equals the supremum, you end up in a circular reasoning.

Some hints for how you should do this: Show that $\tilde x:=\sup{A}\in\overline{A}$ and that $x\leq \tilde x$ for all $x\in\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

First show that $\sup(A)$ (which exists by boundedness of $A$ and completeness of $\mathbb{R}$) is in $\overline{A}$. This follows from the definition of sup and the fact that we have the order topology on the reals. Then at least $\sup(A)$ is a candidate for being $\max(\overline{A})$.